# download gmail contacts

Tags: c#, gmail, google-api, email, email-client

There are lots of script like invite friends script which requests users to provide their google/other account id and password and automatically downloads all email accounts and sends an email invitation automatically. So, how to download email address using ASP.NET C# by providing login details?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a special API for that. Try Googling for it. Can can find the best. Else u can use open invite or email invite 2.1

Answer (score 5):

Use the [Google contacts API](http://code.google.com/apis/contacts/).
Here is a [.NET example of retrieving contacts](http://code.google.com/apis/contacts/docs/3.0/developers_guide_dotnet.html#Retrieving)

Good luck :)